# Every token generated using the Twilio nodejs library is saying "Invalid Signature" in the JWT debugger

Tags: node.js, jwt, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat

Node version: 10.16.0

Twilio NodeJS library: twilio@3.34.0

Twilio Client library: twilio@3.3.1

Every JWT token that I generate using the twilio nodejs library is giving me the error `Invalid Signature` in the JWT debugger in https://jwt.io. I'm able to connect with these invalid tokens and chat without any issues. But I keep getting the warning `20104 - Access Token expired or expiration date invalid` in the twilio debugger console whenever I connect. This the the nodejs code that I use to generate token

```
import twilio from 'twilio';
import config from 'config';

const AccessToken = twilio.jwt.AccessToken;
const ChatGrant = AccessToken.ChatGrant;
const twilioConfig = config.get("twilio");
const {
  apiKey: API_KEY,
  apiSecret: API_SECRET,
  accountSid: ACCOUNT_SID,
  serviceSid: SERVICE_SID
} = twilioConfig;

const chatGrant = new ChatGrant({
  serviceSid: SERVICE_SID,
});

const token = new AccessToken(ACCOUNT_SID, API_KEY, API_SECRET);
token.addGrant(chatGrant);
token.identity = "test@abc.io";
const jwtToken = token.toJwt();
console.log(jwtToken);
```

Comment: did you paste the secret or public key into the key field before you pasted the token on jwt.io? And what's the contents of the exp (expiration timestamp) field in the payload?

Comment: I had not pasted the secret in jwt.io. I did that and that solved the jwt debugger issue. Thank you. The tokens I use have a ttl of 3 hrs. The above code is just an example code I wrote for testing.  When I generate a token for 3 hrs, it checks out in jwt.io also. Any idea why I get the 20104 in twilio? Also when does this log appear is it when I've made a client call with the invalid token or when I try to initialize the client with an invalid token?

Comment: sorry, I don't know anything about twilio. But regarding the expiration, jwt.io doesn't verify the exp, it just checks if the signature is valid. But the the error messages said "expiration date invalid", therefore I wanted to see the exact value. The format has to be a numerical UNIX timestamp.